# jQuery countdown: serverSync still lags for 1-2 seconds by clients

Tags: php, ajax, synchronization, jquery-countdown

I'm building auction site and I'm using jQuery countdown from [Keith Wood](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#serverSync) to show ending time of auctions. I need to have synchronized countdown time with server for all my clients. So far I have implemented jQuery countdown with `serverSync` function. It works fine, but when few seconds pass, countdown lags by 1 or 2 seconds. 
**How can I perfectly synchronize time for all clients, if even possible?**

**UPDATE:** I'm also polling (500ms interval) php file, which updates all auctions (real-time effect) and in this code I also echo out new "polled" countdown from database (because when user bids in last 10 seconds of auction, countdown goes up + 10 seconds). So I think here is the problem, cause on the client side, not every poll starts in the same time,  it depends when client refreshes page and so one and it affects countdown. **Basically every 500ms I call in my poll.php this (which updates the countdown from database):**

```
var syncDate = new Date("'.$formatEndDate.'");  
jq("#defaultCountdown-'.$bidded_id.'").countdown("option", {until: syncDate, serverSync: serverTime});
```

**My code so far, which lags for 1 or 2 seconds:**

```
$(function () {
   var d = new Date("'.$endingDate.'");             
   $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: d,  onExpiry: endAuction, 
     expiryText: '<div class="bid-over">Ended</div>', format: 'HMS', 
     onTick: watchCountdown, serverSync: serverTime });
});

function serverTime() {
var time = null;
var url = "serverTime.php";
jq.ajax({
    url: url,
    async: false,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (text) {
        time = new Date(text);
    },
    error: function (http, message, exc) {
        time = new Date();

    }
});
return time;
}
```

and **serverTime.php:**

```
<?php
//This is how I get server time
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1 
header("Expires: Fri, 1 Jan 2010 00:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past 
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"); // MIME type 
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Ljubljana');
$srvDate = getdate();
$d = $srvDate['mday'];
$m = $srvDate['mon'];
$y = $srvDate['year'];
$h = $srvDate['hours'];
$i = $srvDate['minutes'];
$s = $srvDate['seconds'];
$nowDate=date("$y-$m-$d $h:$i:$s");
$nowDate=str_replace("-","/",$nowDate);
echo $nowDate;
?>
```

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php: Instead of using this function to set the default timezone in your script, you can also use the INI setting date.timezone to set the default timezone. You can also replace your `getdate` code with `echo date('Y/m/d h:i:s')`. This will make serverTime.php faster maybe.

Comment: I'll try with INI. Isn't this `echo date('Y/m/d h:i:s')` clients date? I need date from server, this is why I `getDate()`. Or is there any "faster" way to get server time and not client time?

Comment: date() will return server date/time